# Añadir más info a mark en google maps API 3

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Tengo un mapa dentro de mi aplicación web, el cuál muestra marcadores de mi base de datos. Utilizo la opción de clustering de google maps.

Como se ve en el siguiente código, utilizo lat y lng (guardados previamente en mi base de datos) para generar marcadores.

Buscando en la documentación de google maps api no he sabido cómo poner más información a cada marcador

La idea es que al dar click en el marcador, se abra un modal con la info de ese registro en mysql, en eso no hay problema. La cosa es ¿Cómo agrego, por ejemplo, un id o class o tag a cada marcador?

Basicamente, quiero implementar esto
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

```js
 <script>

      function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 41.6041581, lng: -3.980962}
        });

        var labels = '';

        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length],
          });
        });

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }
      var locations = [

      <?php
      foreach ($rows as $row) {
    ?>
     <?php if ($row['parametro'] != "5"): ?>
        <?php echo "{lat: " . $row['lat'] . ", lng: " . $row['lng'] . "},"; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>
    <?php } ?>

      ]
     

   </script>
```

Así se generan las localizaciones

```js
var locations = [

        {lat: 43.298215, lng: -1.961528},
        {lat: 42.25115, lng: -2.841528},
        {lat: 44.818215, lng: -1.05528},
  
          ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Que tal creo que no has tenido alguna respuesta sobre esto, pero mira lo ideal para agregar "markers" es que construyas todo dentro de un array y utilices el método de :

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Te hago muestra de como lo puedes hacer con un ejemplo básico, ya que los clusters son agrupaciones de "markers" y por lo que veo en tu código no necesitas eso exactamente.

En el código hago comentarios de como es que lo puedes ir agregando la información

IMPORTANTE : Coloca tu api key

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>mapa markers</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map{
            position: relative;
            height: 400px;
            width:  600px;
        }
        .strong{ color:blue; font-size: 16px; margin:0; padding: 0px 4px; font-weight: 600; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&sensor=false"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var markers = [];
var icon_ = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/font-awesome/1792/map-marker-32.png";

// con código PHP lo puedes agregar directamente 
// en él codigo los estilos y etiquetas 
// que vayas a necesitar
//puedes agregar todo el contenido que necesites
var locations =
[
     [ 
     '<p class="strong">Pin 1</p>', 
     19.51470699999999, //lat
     -99.23468530000002,//lon
     icon_,
     'Circuitos Ingenieros , Naucalpan, Estado de México',
     ],
     [
     '<p class="strong">Pin 2</p>', 
     19.551949086551126,//lat
     -99.21684602117921,//lon
     icon_,
     'Calle Toronto, Valle Dorado, Naucalpan, Estado de México',
     ],
     [
     '<p class="strong">Pin 3</p>', 
     19.516052,//lat
     -99.24307299999998,//lon
     icon_,
     'EDOMEX',
     ],
];


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 12,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.516052,-99.24307299999998),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {               

     //access to global - var #markers
     markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),//lat,lon
          map: map,//mapa
          icon: locations[i][3]//custom icon
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
               infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]+"<br>"+locations[i][4]); //puede ser contenido HTML
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
     })(markers[i], i));
}       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te adjunto una captura de pantalla de como es el resultado